# Cherry-pick during Rebase

Tags: git

I'm backporting commits onto a local instance of the Linux kernel. Let's call the branches **Upstream** and **Local**.

I've cherry-picked the commit series, say, **Upstream~10..Upstream** onto **Local**. I've fixed up the conflicts, and am now interactive rebasing to edit the commits so things actually build and work [1]. I need to pull in dependencies (and transitive dependencies) of the commit series.

When I cherry-pick during the interactive rebase, it dumps the commit into my stage, rather than inserting the commit into the tree after the commit that I chose to edit. *How do I accomplish that or something similar?*

I can think of some bad options, but no good ones:

1. Manually commit: copy paste the old commit message, fixup the author/etc, and then later fix-up the patch ordering (dependcies should probably go first).
2. Abort the rebase, cherry-pick the commit, and restart the interactive rebase (and move the cherry-picked dependency to the front).
3. Option 2, but shove any partial work into the stash and `git rebase --continue` until the end instead of using abort.
4. Concede, and amend the dependency onto the commit I'm editing.

None of these options seem great, and it seems like there should be something better. Particularly if I start rebasing and mid-rebase I realize I need some particular commit. Is there a way around this?  Option 3 is probably what I will end up doing, but it feels a little tedious.

Plausibly the answer is no, since cherry-picking during a rebase may require you to nest merge-conflict-resolution-sessions (not sure if there is a name for this), and that sounds rather difficult for git to implement.

[1] Had I been a wiser I probably would have done this during the initial cherry-pick, but I'm not certain that would have done anything differently.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean by "patch" here?

Comment: Swapped all instances of patch for commit. Was mixing usage of terms from different contexts. Calling a patch series a commit series seems weird, but whatever.

Comment: I ended up aborting the interactive rebase, checking out Local again, and alternating cherry-picks from dependencies and the old Local..Local-With-Upstream-Cherrypicks.

Comment: I think the solution better than the current would be to have the cherry-pick fail completely instead of adding to the stage (horrible idea!), if nesting a cherry-pick inside of the rebase is too complicated. Nobody expects that when running a cherry-pick command; no specific message was given either.